# How can I make my ckEditor menu buttons show up on two rows instead of four?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I downloaded the ckEditor full package. The toolbar buttons appear on four rows but I have a very wide editor window area and I would like to cut this down to two or three. Can someone help by giving me some advice on how I could change this. I did look at the documentation but I have to say I am more confused than ever. I am not sure if I should be dealing with toolbar groups and not sure which group is which.

Does anyone have examples of what they have done.

Comment: Depends are you looking at using the groups or customizing your toolbar, and what is your current toolbar config?

Comment: Right now I have no toolbar config. I am just using the default config.js . I am okay to use groups or anything that would be the most simple way for me to combine onto two lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should 2 things:

1. make your textarea wider
2. delete some `'/'` from your config file, as it means newline in configuration

   config.toolbar_Custom =
       [
           { name: 'document', items : [ 'Preview' ] },
           { name: 'clipboard', items : [ 'Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo' ] },
           { name: 'editing', items : [ 'Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','-','Scayt' ] },
           { name: 'insert', items : [ 'Image','Table','HorizontalRule','SpecialChar','PageBreak' ] },
           { name: 'links', items : [ 'Link','Unlink' ] },
                   '/',
           { name: 'styles', items : [ 'Styles','Format' ] },
           { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic','Strike','-','RemoveFormat' ] },
           { name: 'paragraph', items : [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','-','Blockquote' ] },
           { name: 'tools', items : [ 'Maximize' ] }
       ];

This is the 2 lines toolbar which I use.

Comment: You mention about deleting / from my config file. But I just downloaded the default and there is not config.toolbar_Custom. Is your 2 line toolbar based on the full plugin package ? Thanks

Comment: Check simple build-config.js or ckEditor.js

Comment: Thanks I will do that. By the way I tried your config but it does not seem to do anything at all. Is there someplace that I should define it to use config.toolbar_Custom ?

Comment: Wrap the code above width:

CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
     config.language = 'uk';
    // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
    config.toolbar = 'Custom';

`here goes the code`

 
    config.removePlugins = 'elementspath';
};